# Could I report some websites that blatantly mirror Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, legal, scraping

In the last two months I had found some websites that blatantly mirror or some of them blatantly crawl the questions and answers, and provide some translations.

Is this ok to report here?

For example: 
https://www.it-swarm.dev/id/.net/grafik-ketergantungan-proyek-visual-studio/957825213/

That URL is the raw translation (from English to Indonesian) of my answer on Stack Overflow:
[Dependency graph of Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects/598134#598134)

Therefore I suggest Stack Overflow team should check this problem. If it's possible, close the copycat website.

PS: To the Stack Overflow team and Stack Overflow meta moderators, feel free to edit the tags of this question, if the tags I put here are wrong.

**UPDATE:**

My question might be the same with the reasoned duplicate question, but my point is this: the suspected website does include the attribution, but it blatantly providing translation to other languages such as Indonesian, and the intention is totally different from the original. Some of the sentences translated into a total non-sense semantic.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks! the link you mentioned is quite the same.

Comment: BTW, the website includes cc attribution, but the translation destroy the meaning of the Q n A, and the intent is totally different from the original QnA.

Comment: If the site properly attributes, they can do pretty much anything they want with it. It doesn't have to be Q&A. They can use the content to write a play, as an inspirational text to a brownie recipe, for a political rally, anything. Your only right is that you can request de-association, that your name and any reference to you is removed from the content.

Comment: If the translations are poor quality, then that's really their problem, not ours.

Comment: I understand. But the website contains questions and answers that when translated raw, it contradicts the original intent of the QnA and the links in the QnA still points back to the original SO. In some sense it may bring damages in the long run.

Comment: The answer to the question I linked to mentions using the Contact Us form to report the scraper. You can also use that form to report your concerns with the translation. There's really nothing Meta regulars or even moderators can do about the site, beyond those available to individuals for the content provided by those individuals under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: thanks! I already reported the website from the Contact Us form.